# A Condition a Conditional Probability Should Satisfy

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, conditional

Consider four random variables $V_1,V_2,V_3, V_4$.

Here, suppose that $V_2$ is a function of $V_3$ and $V_4$, say $V_2=V_3-V_4$.

In this case, I want to know whether the following conditional probability implicitly imposes a restriction on the conditional value of $V_2$:
$$f(V_1|V_2,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4).$$

The point I am curious is whether, in the conditional tern, the relationship $V_2=V_3-V_4$ should hold.

To be specific, In my personal guess, the conditional probability should satisfy
$$f(V_1|V_2<v_3-v_4,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4).$$

If my guess is correct, the restriction can be applied to the condtional expectation:

In the following conditional expectation,
$$\mathbb{E}[V_1|V_2, V_3<v3, V_4<v_4],$$

the value of $V_2$ should be less than $v_3-v_4$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Is there a typo in $V_1|V_2,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4$ ? Do you mean $V_1|V_2=v_2,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4$ ? Or $V_1|V_2<v_2,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V_2$ is a deterministic function of $(V_3,V_4)$, there are only three rv's to consider in this question/homework. In particular, the event  $$V_2<v_2,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4$$
only depends on the distribution of $(V_3,V_4)$, as it can be expressed as
$$V_3-V_4<v_2,V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4$$
Note that
$$V_3<v_3,V_4<v_4$$
does not imply
$$V_3-V_4<v_3-v_4$$
but only
$$V_3-v_4<V_3-V_4<v_3-V_4$$

Comment: So, then, it does not matter whether we include $V_3-V_4$ or not in the conditional term. Right?

Comment: The event is modified if $V_3-V_4<v_2$ but it is characterised by the joint distribution of $(V_3,V_4)$.